# Can monit test for a response from a node API call?

Tags: node.js, api, monit

I have a `node` API with serious code quality issues that can't be fixed -- because managers -- so very often requests stop being answered **but the node process is still running**.

I'm using `upstart` to run node as a service and `monit` to keep it running. My very simple `monitrc` is only looking for the PID of the running node process, so it's not detecting this 'zombie' node process that needs to be restarted. My bright idea is to write a simple API method that would respond "OK", and have monit attempt that request along with looking for the node PID. Is this possible? Is there a better way?

Google-ing combinations of "monit" and "node`" leads me to lengthy blog posts about remote performance monitoring node applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fire a `GET` request and check its answer with [connection tests](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#CONNECTION-TESTS):

```
    if failed
        host 127.0.0.1
        port 80
        protocol http
        request "/"
        content = "foobar"
    then restart
```

or its state

```
    if failed
        host 127.0.0.1
        port 80
        protocol http
        request "/fooBarApi"
        status = 200
    then restart
```

I really recommend to read [the manual](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html) - monit has some awesome features you might not expect  ;)